# How can i merge every block of 3 lines together while ignoring lower numbers of consecutive lines?

Tags: awk

I have a text file like the following, contains blocks of text, blocks are in multiples of 3 lines or just 1 line:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEEEE
FFFFFFFFFFFFF

GGGGGGGGGGGGG

HHHHHHHHHHHHH
IIIIIIIIIIIII
JJJJJJJJJJJJJ

KKKKKKKKKKKKK

LLLLLLLLLLLLL
MMMMMMMMMMMMM
NNNNNNNNNNNNN
OOOOOOOOOOOOO
PPPPPPPPPPPPP
QQQQQQQQQQQQQ
RRRRRRRRRRRRR
SSSSSSSSSSSSS
TTTTTTTTTTTTT

UUUUUUUUUUUUU

VVVVVVVVVVVVV
WWWWWWWWWWWWW
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
1111111111111
```

I would like to merge every block of 3 consecutive lines together, starting with the first in the block. I want to ignore lines that are in less then a block of 3 consecutive lines.
Characters and lengths of lines are always different. ( i have made the lines the same size in the example so it doesn't look too ugly).

So the output would be

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDD EEEEEEEEEEEEE FFFFFFFFFFFFF

GGGGGGGGGGGGG

HHHHHHHHHHHHH IIIIIIIIIIIII JJJJJJJJJJJJJ

KKKKKKKKKKKKK

LLLLLLLLLLLLL MMMMMMMMMMMMM NNNNNNNNNNNNN
OOOOOOOOOOOOO PPPPPPPPPPPPP QQQQQQQQQQQQQ
RRRRRRRRRRRRR SSSSSSSSSSSSS TTTTTTTTTTTTT

UUUUUUUUUUUUU

VVVVVVVVVVVVV WWWWWWWWWWWWW XXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYY ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ 1111111111111
```

I have tried to use

```
xargs -n3
```

However im not sure how to ignore singular lines

How can i acheive this?

Comment: @Quasímodo i added my attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk -v FS="\n" -v RS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=3)print $i,$(i+1),$(i+2);print ""}' file
```

Output:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDD EEEEEEEEEEEEE FFFFFFFFFFFFF

GGGGGGGGGGGGG  

HHHHHHHHHHHHH IIIIIIIIIIIII JJJJJJJJJJJJJ

...
```

**Update** Version that won't leave trailing space:

```
$ awk -v FS="\n" -v RS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s%s",$i,(i%3==0||i==NF?ORS:OFS);print ""}' file
```

Please see discussion on some features in the comments. Thanks to the commentators for the constructive feedback.

Comment: That would print blank chars at the end of lines that aren't 3 strings - is that OK?

Comment: @kvantour Wait, which one and why?

Comment: Imagine a tab or a space in one of the lines. It is possible that the presented data is an oversimplification of reality.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for `gensub()`:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{$1=$1; print gensub(/(([^ ]+ ){2}[^ ]+) /,"\\1\n","g")}' file
AAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDD EEEEEEEEEEEEE FFFFFFFFFFFFF

GGGGGGGGGGGGG

HHHHHHHHHHHHH IIIIIIIIIIIII JJJJJJJJJJJJJ

KKKKKKKKKKKKK

LLLLLLLLLLLLL MMMMMMMMMMMMM NNNNNNNNNNNNN
OOOOOOOOOOOOO PPPPPPPPPPPPP QQQQQQQQQQQQQ
RRRRRRRRRRRRR SSSSSSSSSSSSS TTTTTTTTTTTTT

UUUUUUUUUUUUU

VVVVVVVVVVVVV WWWWWWWWWWWWW XXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYY ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ 1111111111111
```

Comment: @kvantour why? `\n` is already included in the set of chars uses as separators when you use the default FS and if there are any other space chars present in the file we don't want to exclude them.

Comment: Imagine that there is a space or tab in the list of characters. I believe the example data is an oversimplification of actual real data. Maybe the columns are just aligned on n characters and the OP just made it simple. By avoiding tabs and spaces and indicating directly that a newline is the only allowed field separator, it becomes "safer"

Comment: If there's a space or tab in the list of characters then I expect it's just a trailing space at the end of a line and so should be included with `\n` in the set of contiguous chars that separate fields so IMHO leaving the FS as-is is "safer". I guess we'll see what the OP says... In the scenario you describe, though, my script would need more changes than just setting FS to `\n` since the gensub() is replacing based on blank chars only being present as part of the field separators.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different which will always work:

```
awk '(NF==0){print rec ORS; rec="";c=0; next}
     {rec = rec (c ? (c%3==0 ? ORS : OFS) : "") $0; c++ }
     END {print rec}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\S/{N;/\n\s*$/b;N;//b;s/\n/ /g}' file
```

If the current line is not empty, append the next line.

If the appended line is not empty, append the next line.

If that line is also not empty, replace the newlines by spaces.

In all other cases print the line(s) as is.

An alternative, that is more programmatic:

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/&/2;Ta;/^\s*$/M{P;D};s/\n/ /g' file
```